# Problema com float python (uri 1098)

Tags: python, float

Estou tentando resolver este [problema](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/repository/UOJ_1098.html) e quando executo o codigo, em determinado ponto ele para de funcionar corretamente. Penso que seja por causa do arredondamento, porém quando é retirado essa parte, o codigo executa ao infinito.

```
i = 0
j = 1

while(i != 2.2):
    print('I=%s J=%s' % (i, j))
    j = j + 1
    if(j == (i + 4)):
        i = round(i + 0.2, 1)
        j = round(j - 2.8, 1)
```

existe alguma função que seja melhor trabalhar com casas decimais?

Comment: Parece-me que funciona bem. A que problema se está a referir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu codigo parece-me funcionar bem.

Quanto a executar até ao infinito creio que é por causa da logica no seu `while`. Para responder à sua questão:

> existe alguma função que seja melhor trabalhar com casas decimais?

Sim existe o modulo [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html). Uma possível solução:

```
from decimal import Decimal

i = 0
j = 1
while(i <= 2):
    print('I={} J={}'.format(i, j))
    j = j + 1
    if(j == (i + 4)):
        i += Decimal('0.2')
        j -= Decimal('2.8')
```

Referência: [Python Cookbook, 3rd edition](https://vk.com/doc169496702_353141701?hash=e9c928518cdf27b23c&dl=01490c577abb6a6b29) pags: 102/103 (84/85 no rodapé)

Answer (score 0):

Esta questão se refere ao desafio de número **1098**, cujo título é **Sequencia IJ 4** disponibilizada por **Uri Online Judge**.

[Veja aqui](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1098) a íntegra do enunciado.

Para resolver esta questão devemos desenvolver um algoritmo que seja capaz de `reproduzir` o exemplo que foi dado na referida questão.

Para resolver esta questão corretamente podemos implementa o seguinte algoritmo...

```
i = 0
j = 1
acrescimo = (0.2)
n = 0
while i <= 2:
    for c in range(1, 4):
        if i > 2.19:
            print('I={:.0f} J={:.0f}'.format(2, j))
        if i == 1.0 or i == 0.0 or i > 1.8:
            print('I={:.0f} J={:.0f}'.format(i, j))
        elif i < 2:
            print('I={:.1f} J={:.1f}'.format(i, j))
        j = j + 1
    i = i + acrescimo
    j = 1 + i
```

Veja o funcionamento do algoritmo no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/xozjrzqj-solkarped).

Esta questão já foi `testada`, `submetida` e devidamente `aprovada` no site do `URI`, sob linguagem de programação `Python 3`.